# Angular 5: New data merged with old

Tags: angular

I'm very new to Angular and have an issue with an application I am working on. Basically, we have a Content Component that displays some data that is fetched through an API call in a service. There is also a header component that has a search form, which shows a list of suggested results. Clicking on a result routes to the Content Component to display the results. This is done just using routing to point to the Content Component.

However, if you are looking at data in the Content Component, then search for something and click a result, the new data gets merged into the existing data in the Content Component, rather than refreshing it.

The Content Component call:

```
  private getData(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.apiService.getData(params['id']).subscribe(result => {
        this.resultsList = result;
        this.fillDataArray(this.resultsList, params['id']);
      });
    });
  }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me your complete code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that `this.fillDataArray` always pushes the items to existing array and never clears it. First step in `this.fillDataArray` should be to clear the array, e.g with `this.dataArray.length = 0`

Answer (score 0):

if your resultList is an array you can simply set the

```
 this.resultList = null;
```

before assigning new data as

```
 this.resultList = result;
```

try rewriting your code as

```
 private getData(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.apiService.getData(params['id']).subscribe(result => {
        this.resultList = null;
        setTimeout(()=>{
         this.resultList = result;
         this.fillDataArray(this.resultsList, params['id']);
        },1000);

      });
    });
  }
```

right off the bat i think that should work, but let me know if that solves your problem